# Firebase function unauthenticated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a new firebase function I deployed with firebase cli tool that is returning a unauthenticated api error when called from the application. I have updated the permissions on the function in gcloud to allUsers / invoke / allow unauthenticated, but this does not fix the issue. This is the extent of troubleshooting i have seen suggested on similar threads, has anyone been able to fix this issue at this point?

Comment: Tried signing out with `firebase logout`, upgrading to the latest cli version with `npm i -g firebase-tools` and then signing back in again with `firebase login`?

Comment: @samthecodingman just tried, did not work.

Comment: Where is the source of the error? In the Firebase CLI? On the Cloud Functions host? In the Cloud Function's source? Can you provide the code that you are using to call the function and the code that defines the function?

Comment: The error is reported from the frontend applications api cli. The function is a pub/sub function that runs fine scheduled, but when called from the application it fails unauthenticated. therefore the issue is not with the function

Comment: RE: Requesting code - While the problem may not be caused by a direct code issue, having code to test allows us to deploy our own copy of your function to investigate with.

Comment: @samthecodingman it is objectively unrelated. this is likely either an environment issue or console issue

Comment: Try `firebase functions:delete yourFunction` and then redeploy it. If that doesn't solve it, you are dealing with some internal issue that's going to need you to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact). Whatever the outcome, don't forget to report back here to add it to the knowledge base.

Comment: Hey, Can you show us your Firebase rules? and are you using Firebase Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pubsub functions cannot be called via https either with those permissions or through that api as done with regular https functions. I'm unsure if this is possible at all, I created a secondary duplicate function as a standard https function with the required permissions and it now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I often encounter the same problem. **Try redeploying.** Most of the time it works.